# Two quick questions about flex / C

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I would like to use this idiom :

```
    yy_scan_string(line);
    int i;
    while ((i = yylex()))
        ....
```

where these two functions are define in the flex generated lex.yy.c in my main C file. So far, I am

```
 #including "lex.yy.c"
```

but it seems fishy. How do I do that the correct C way?
Secondly, I would like the last line of my .l file,

```
.                   {   return WORD; }
```

to no longer return a "WORD" token, but rather to return its input. For exemple (it is a smallish linux shell)

```
 ls > ls.txt
```

Currently returns 2 WORD tokens, a GREATER token, and 6 WORD tokens, when I would like a return of "ls" GREATER "ls.txt". Of course yylex() can only return one type, so what is the accepted way to obtain the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to **declare** the functions (and later link the implementation files together). You don't need to include .c files in order to use the functions defined in them.

Comment: You could use `. { return *yytext; }` to return the character that was read.  You'd use `'<'` in the grammar, then.  It isn't recommended, but you could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `flex` to generate a header file as well as the C source file, using the `--header-file=<filename>` command line option, or by including `%option header-file="<filename>"` in the flex source. I typically invoke `flex` with:

```
flex --header-file=file.h -o file.c file.l
```

(Actually, I use `make` rules to generate a command like that, but that's the idea.) Then you can `#include "file.h"` in any source file which needs to invoke a flex function.

Normally, `yylex` returns the token type (an integer). The global variable `yytext` contains a pointer to the token string itself, which is probably sufficient for your purposes. However, please read ["A Note About yytext And Memory"](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html) in the `flex` manual. (Summary: if you need to save the value of `yytext`, you must make a copy of it; `strdup` is recommended. Don't forget to free the copy when you don't need it anymore.)

Sometimes, the token string itself is not exactly what you want as a semantic value. By convention, `flex` actions place the semantic value of the token in the global `yylval`, which is where `bison`-generated parsers will look for it. However, `yylval` is not declared anywhere by `flex`-generated code, so you need to include a declaration yourself, both in the flex-generated code and in any source file which includes it. (If you use `bison` to generate your parser, `bison` will generate this declaration and put it in the header file it generates.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. These tools look really useful, but are a little advanced for my competency level, and you really helped!